# How to manipulate a div when clicking link in current list item

Tags: jquery, list

I have a list of items which contains a div and a link e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">
       <div class="div1"></div>
       <a class="link1"></a>
   </li>
   <li class="item">
      <div class="div1"></div>
      <a class="link1"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
     <div class="div1"></div>
    <a class="link1"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to click the link in a list item (link1) and update/manipulate the div content (div1) for the current list item. click the link in an other list item should do the same to it's corresponding div.

Any help on how I can get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $("li.item a.link1").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("div.div1").html("Yeah, that's the manipulated div.");
  });
});
```

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.link1").click(function(){
        var div1 =  $(this).prev("div.div1")
        //Do something with div1
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[class^='link']").click(function () {
    var div = $(this).siblings("div");
    // Update div
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tqDsD/